# Qualquer exe gerado pode ser executado ou depende da plataforma que foi feito?

Tags: sistema-operacional, arquitetura-computadores, .exe

Peguei alguns arquivos do sistema operacional DOS com a extensão `.exe` e os executei numa máquina virtual e num emulador DOSBOX. Depois testei-os em uma máquina física. O resultado entre ambos: máquina física, máquina virtual e "máquina" do tipo emulada foi o mesmo.

Eles abriram e executaram o arquivo

Com os códigos fontes compilados na máquina virtual VirtualBox tinha vários arquivos para o funcionamento. Funcionava de modo semelhante e até parecida com a máquina física e também na máquina emulada. Porém, suas instruções não eram as mesmas de ambas. Não era o mesmo código que a máquina física ou da máquina emulada. Tinha uma enorme diferença. Entretanto, funcionava.

Vi alguns artigos, descobrir sobre Turing e a história de sua máquina.

Por que o Linux não pode executar nativamente chamando o Virtualbox ou entre outras máquinas emuladas, arquivos `.exe` e rodá-los? Li sobre Wine e testei. Não roda alguns jogos que quero. DOSBOX tem alguns arquivos que não rodam e outros que rodam.

Comment: A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo

Answer (score 3):

Depende da plataforma. Um executável é um conjunto de instruções que determinam o que a máquina deve fazer, então se ele usa instruções que uma plataforma não entende não vai funcionar. É como dizer que você pode chegar no Japão e será compreendido. Não vai. Cada um com seu jeito.

Até existem técnicas para fazer isto acontecer, mas é uma camada de abstração e um conjunto de ferramentas que tornará possível, ou seja, é como você ter um tradutor de português-japonês.